Unable to listen the azure iot hub events using mqtt library in node.js
var mqtt = require("mqtt");
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var host = "iothub.azure-devices.net";
var deviceId = "test";
var sharedKey = "xxxSharedKeyxxx";


var publishtopic = "devices/" + deviceId + "/messages/devicebound/#";
var subscribetopic = "devices/" + deviceId + "/messages/events/";

function encodeUriComponentStrict(str) {
   return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function (c) {
   return "%" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
 });
 }

 function getSaSToken(hostName, deviceId, sharedKey) {
 var sr = encodeUriComponentStrict(hostName + "/devices/" + deviceId);
 var se = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 24 * 3600;
 var StringToSign = sr + "\n" + se;
 var sig = encodeUriComponentStrict(
   CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
     StringToSign,
     CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(sharedKey)
   ).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
 );
 return "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + sr + "&sig=" + sig + "&se=" + se;
 }

 var client = mqtt.connect({
 hostname: "iothub.azure-devices.net",
 port: 8883,
 protocol: "mqtts",
 protocolVersion: 4,
 clientId:"test,
 username: "iothub.azure-devices.net/test/?api-version=2021-04-12",
 password: getSaSToken(host, deviceId, sharedKey),
 rejectUnauthorized: false,
 });

 client.on("connect", function (packet) {
 console.log(" sub mqtt connected!", packet);
 client.subscribe(subscribetopic);
 });

 client.on("reconnect", function () {
 console.log("mqtt reconnected!");
 });

 client.on("close", function (c) {
 console.log("mqtt closed!", c);
 });

  client.on("message", function (topic, message, packet) {
  var string = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(message);
  console.log("receive!", string);
 });



The above code is getting reconnected as the iot device send message to the Azure Hub.And we are not able to get the data published by the device on Azure Iot Hub.
We have used "azure iot hub sdk" available for node.js. Using that we can comfortably send and receive messages to iot device.
We are subscribing to the "events" topic in the above code and when the device send message the code is reconnecting instead of subscribing to the events.
And also when we are publishing to the "devicebound" topic then we are getting OsError on device side.
Our Iot device is using micro-python code.

Can you please enable logging and add the log content to your question? Please also confirm what Client ID your "Device" is using (if it's also "test" then that is probably your issue). You may find mqttx useful for testing (if this works then the issue is with your app, otherwise it's somehting else).

@user28052177 Could you please check my answer

The az iot hub monitor-events command is designed only for monitoring device telemetry and messages sent to an IoT Hub.
Since your code does not currently has a message-sending part, no events are being sent.
Add the following sample code to send telemetry data:
  const telemetryMessage = {
        temperature: 22,
        humidity: 60,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    };
    console.log('Sending telemetry data:', telemetryMessage);
    client.publish(topic, JSON.stringify(telemetryMessage), { qos: 1 });

Below code is for sending telemetry messages to IoT Hub and receiving telemetry messages from IoT Hub:
I followed this link to use MQTT for communicating with Azure IoT Hub.
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const deviceId = "<YourDeviceID>";
const deviceKey = "<YourDeviceKey>";
const iotHubHostName = "<YourIoTHubName>.azure-devices.net"; 
const topic = `devices/${deviceId}/messages/events/`; 
const clientId = `${deviceId}`;

function generateSasToken(uri, deviceKey, expiry = 3600) {
    const decodedKey = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(deviceKey);
    const encodedUri = encodeURIComponent(uri);
    const expiryTime = Math.floor((Date.now() / 1000) + expiry);

    const stringToSign = `${encodedUri}\n${expiryTime}`;
    const hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, decodedKey);
    const signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hmac);

    return `SharedAccessSignature sr=${encodedUri}&sig=${encodeURIComponent(signature)}&se=${expiryTime}`;
}

const mqttOptions = {
    clientId: clientId,
    username: `${iotHubHostName}/${deviceId}/?api-version=2018-06-30`, 
    password: generateSasToken(`devices/${deviceId}`, deviceKey), 
    clean: true,
    reconnectPeriod: 1000,
};

const client = mqtt.connect(`mqtts://${iotHubHostName}:8883`, mqttOptions);

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to Azure IoT Hub');

    const telemetryMessage = {
        temperature: 22,
        humidity: 60,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    };
    console.log('Sending telemetry data:', telemetryMessage);
    client.publish(topic, JSON.stringify(telemetryMessage), { qos: 1 });

    const cloudToDeviceTopic = `devices/${deviceId}/messages/devicebound/#`; 
    client.subscribe(cloudToDeviceTopic, { qos: 1 }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to subscribe:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Subscribed to cloud-to-device messages');
        }
    });
});

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    console.log('Received message from IoT Hub:', topic, message.toString());
 
});
client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Connection error:', err);
    client.end();
});

client.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected from Azure IoT Hub');
});

client.on('reconnect', () => {
    console.log('Reconnecting...');
});


Output:

Azure CLI Ouput :
To monitor events in Azure CLI, use the following command:
az iot hub monitor-events --output table --device-id mydevice --hub-name {YourIoTHubName}


The sent message body will be displayed in received message from IoT Hub  of the code .

